# What is the alternative solution for window.localStorage with vuex-persistentstate for manifest-v3?

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, vuex, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I recently have migrated  browser-extension from manifest-v2 to manifest-v3, now in v3, window.localStorage is undefined because window and DOM can not be used with service-worker.
I am using this library **vuex-persistentstate** to sync my **localStorage** and Vuex, but its not working out any more.

I tried to use browser.storage.local instead of localStorage , but it's not working as its asynchronous.

Comment: I think you need to present your manifest.json and source code.

Comment: There is no synchronous storage available in bg service worker in MV3. You can use `storage.local` or `storage.session` or `IndexedDB`.

Comment: If you really want synchronous storage you can fake it yourself via a `Proxy`, but why do you even need Vue in the service worker? Simply use it and localStorage in your visible page, no problem.

Comment: localStorage isnt working in bg of service worker because there is no access window globally.